# Creating and adding object from base class to derived class array

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have an issue with creating and adding objects into an array
This is my base class:

```
class CPerson
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    int birth_year;
    char sex;


public:
    CPerson();
    CPerson(std::string, std::string,int,char);
```

with some extra setters and getters. Then I have this derived class:

```
class CData :
    public CPerson
{
    int nrOfPersons;
    CPerson *Data_array; 
public:
    CData(int);
    ~CData();
};
```

In the constructor I want to fill the Data_array with person objects , and I do the following:

```
CData::CData(int x) : nrOfPersons(x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfPersons; i++)
        Data_array[i] = CPerson();
}
```

But it crashes halfway there. I made the default `CPerson()` constructor to `cout` a message "Inserted" everytime I use it. So if I call in main `CData database(4)` it should print "Inserted" 4 times on the screen. Instead it only prints 2 times and then it crashes.

Comment: where do you allocate the memory to `Data_array`?

Comment: CData shouldn't inherit from CPerson. A list of people is not a person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a pointer to `CPerson` as an array. That would be true if you had dynamically allocated an array at construction, but that's a lot of hassle you don't really want to deal with.

Thankfully the C++ standard created a very useful utility called [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), that you can use:

```
class CData : public CPerson
{
    std::vector<CPerson> Data_array;
    // ...
};
```

and then:

```
CData::CData(int n) 
    : Data_array(n)
    {}
```

And the most beautiful thing about this is that your `nrOfPersons` member object also magically disappears. To retrieve the size you can just call `Data_array.size()` and voilà.

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate memory for `Data_array`:

```
CData::CData(int x) : nrOfPersons(x)
{
    // allocate memory
    Data_array = new CPerson[nrOfPersons];

    // fill array
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfPersons; i++)
        Data_array[i] = CPerson();
}
```

Don't forget to delete the allocated array afterwards (in a destructor for instance):

```
delete[] Data_array
```

Comment: Deleting `Data_array` in the destructor is not the only thing required to make this class safe.

Comment: Please tell me, which one?

Comment: What do you mean "which one"?

Comment: The other things required

Comment: For example `operator=` should also be overloaded. Second of all what if `CPerson` constructor throws an exception? Then you have memory leak. And so on and on.

Comment: You are right, but adding any operator or making the constructor exception-safe has nothing to do with the array structure but with the class itself.

Comment: What's your point? You are recommending to use `new` in the constructor, and I'm pointing out that by doing so your class is not exception safe. So that is, overall, a terrible advice.

Comment: My point is, memory cannot be accessed before it is allocated, that's all, not about exception safety.